# ContentProvider getWriteableDatabase returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I know this is a common problem, but nothing I've found solves my issue. I've created a ContentProvider, closely following the tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/). My Activity, in its onCreate method immediately after super.onCreate does this:

```
StitchProvider stitchProvider = new StitchProvider();
stitchProvider.delete(STITCHES_URI, null, null);
```

StitchProvider is my ContentProvider. I've followed this code through the debugger and depending on where I put breakpoints, one of two things happen, but both lead to a NullPointerException in LogCat. The first option is I put a breakpoint here:

```
public SQLData(Context c) {
    super(c, DATABASENAME, null, DATABASEVERSION);
}
```

SQLData is my database class. If I put the breakpoint here, I see that c, the Context, is equal to android.app.Application@412a9b80. The code then returns to the onCreate method of StitchProvider:

```
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDB = new SQLData(getContext()); 
    return true;
}
```

and mDB becomes com.MyKnitCards.project.SQLData@412ab668. So far so good I think, but when I try to go past the return statement I get the NullPointerException. If I move the breakpoint to within the delete method of StitchProvider everything goes fine until I get to the getWriteableDatabase line, at which point I get a NullPointerException. Here's the delete method of StitchProvider:

```
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    switch (uriType)
    {
    case STITCHES:
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
        rowsAffected = sqlDB.delete(STITCHTABLE_BASEPATH, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
    case STITCHES_ID:
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDBwithID = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
        String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection))
        {
            rowsAffected = sqlDBwithID.delete(STITCHTABLE_BASEPATH, SQLData.KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
        }
        else
        {
            rowsAffected = sqlDBwithID.delete(STITCHTABLE_BASEPATH, selection + " and " + SQLData.KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, selectionArgs);
        }
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown or Invalid URI " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsAffected;
}
```

One thing I have noticed, is that if I set a breakpoint at SQLData's onCreate method, I never get there. I think part of the problem is that the database is not getting created, but I don't know why. I'll post as much code or LogCat as people want, put I don't want to overwhelm folks with code either.  Anyway, as always, if you have any suggestions, that'd be great, and thanks!

Comment: I hope you're not instantiating the provider on your own as that component must be initialized by the system and then you would use it with `getContentResolver()`(an example http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html ).

Comment: Luksprog - tried to go to the link, but I get a 404 Not Found error. Can you elaborate? I'm an Android newbie and *totally* new to ContentProviders. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't properly copied the link(check it again). The information at that link should solve your problem, I've seen you've done the same mistake on your other question as well.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look. What other question would that be? The one from yesterday about the Uri not matching?

Comment: Yes, I've seen that you instantiate the provider yourself in there as well.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much and please post your answer as an answer so I can vote you up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you instantiate your provider in code, something that you shouldn't be doing as a `ContentProvider` is managed by the Android system. The correct way of using a `ContentProvider` is through a `ContentResolver` which can be obtain in an `Activity` with `getContentResolver()`.

You can find more about `ContentProviders` and how to use them in the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) on the android developers site.